# How to save to Core Data RKMappingResult object in RestKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, restkit

I try to save to Core Data NSManagedObject which I got from server. But I don't know any idea how to save object got from [mappingResult firstObject] in `success block` to Core Data. How can I do this? Should I use `RKObjectManager's postObject` or `RKManagedRequestOperation`? Should I do `[managedObjectContext insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@""]` before this?I can't find any instructions in official docs for this case and need some help.

**EDIT: **I initialise `RKManagedRequestOperation` like this:

```
RKResponseDescriptor* responseDescriptor =[RKResponseDescriptor
                                           responseDescriptorWithMapping:[UserMapping mappingForUser]
                                           method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                           pathPattern:kUserEndpoint
                                           keyPath:@"profile"
                                           statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

RKRequestDescriptor* requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[UserMapping mappingForUserProfileModel] 
                                                                               objectClass:[User class] rootKeyPath:@"profile" method:RKRequestMethodPOST];


[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

userObject =  [User new];

NSDictionary* userParameters = @{ @"user_id" : [User sharedUser].userId};


[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:resumeObject method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                                        path:kUserEndpoint
                                                                  parameters:userParameters];


RKManagedObjectRequestOperation* managedRequest = [[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation alloc]
                                                   initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", kService, kUserEndpoint]]]
                                                   responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];

managedRequest.managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;

[managedRequest setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {


    NSLog(@"MAPPING = %@", [mappingResult firstObject]);


} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] enqueueObjectRequestOperation:managedRequest];
```

**EDIT2:** RestKit doesn't save mapped data to CoreData. But userObject.title saves perfectly:

```
    userObject =  [_managedObjectContext insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User"];
    userObject.title = @"USER_NAME";

    NSDictionary* userParameters = @{ @"user_id" : [User sharedUser].userId};

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:userObject path:kUserEndpoint parameters:userParameters
                                        success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

                                        } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) { }];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take a step back as your suggestions are shooting in the dark.

If you configure your object manager with a managed object store and create response descriptors with entity mappings then when you receive data as a result of requests this will be converted into managed objects. These objects will automatically be saved to the core data store before the success block is called.

Any other objects you want to create can be created as usual and you need to explicitly save the context.

Sending requests with RestKit doesn't itself change the store contents, only the response results in changes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but I have some questions:"These objects will automatically be saved to the core data store before the success block is called.".
How I will know about this? How to retrieve them? And how to initialize RKManagedRequestOperation for this?

Comment: You retrieve them as usual - fetch request (they are also provided in the mapping result). RKManagedRequestOperation is for sending requests to a server which will create managed objects with the response data...

Comment: Can you please tell me how to initialise `RKManagedRequestOperation` for this. See my edits how I did this - I have an exception `the entity (null) is not key value coding-compliant for the key "name"` but my entity has it.

Comment: Sounds like your code data stack isn't set up correctly. Why are you using `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation`? You code doesn't look like you need to, you could just use the manager...

Comment: "Why are you using RKManagedObjectRequestOperation?" because User is `NSManagedObject` subclass...

Comment: All I want is to save object got from server to Core Data entity.

Comment: So, you don't need to create an operation. Just calling `postObject:path:parameters:success:failure:` on the manager will do it more easily.

Comment: Ok. BUT how to save received object to Core Data?

Comment: I have `User* user = [mappingResult firstObject]` -what to do next?This is my main problem. Never mind use I operation or just postObject

Comment: As I said originally, you don't need to do anything. RestKit has already saved the object before it gives you the `mappingResult`.

Comment: Ok thank you very much! I'll accept your answer because you helped me a lot. But I have one more question. Please see my EDIT2 in the question: `user.title` field saved perfectly and I can see it but all the fields which must come from server doesn't save. But you said that RestKit will do it automatically - it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't actually show any mapping used by the response descriptor or the result JSON in your question so I can't say. It could be the key path `@"profile"` on the response descriptor...

Comment: I actually really forgot to add them. But after adding - I got an exception `NSManagedObjects of entity User do not support mutableValueForKey: for the property skills`. And this is for all properties which is NSArray. May be this is the reason?

Comment: It seems RestKit can't map an array of objects or what?

Comment: What is the property type? It should be `transformable` if you're setting it to an array.

Comment: I suggest starting a new question and showing the mappings, response descriptors, JSON and entity definition...

Comment: Yes it is set as `transformable` in `xcdatamodel` and in object it is `NSArray` of custom `Skill` objects

Comment: And `Skill` objects is `NSCoding`-complaint - I implement `encodewithCoder` and `initwithcoder`

Comment: If I just fill this object manually and then save it to Core Data - everything good. But after `postObject` I got this exception

Comment: Then I guess your mapping is asking RestKit to use a relationship rather than treat as an array. New question is required.

Comment: Ok thank you. I have created a new question with detail explanation of the problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319348/cant-map-array-of-objects-for-nsmanagedobject-in-restkit   
Please look at it and help me if you can. I really need to solve this problem and it makes me crazy

Answer (score 2):

See this tutorial. There is an example of using RestKit with object management and Code Data

https://github.com/alexanderedge/RestKitTutorial1