# Can't map an array of objects for NSManagedObject in RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, restkit

I have `User` class which is `NSManagedObject` subclass:

```
@interface User : NSManagedObject

  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * about;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * contactAddress;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * contactEmail;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * hobbies;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* jobExperience;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * surname;
@end
```

As you can see this object has an NSArray property of objects `JobExperience`. `JobExperience` defined as follows:

```
@interface JobExperience : NSObject <NSCoding>

 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* position;
 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* organization;
 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* dateFrom;
 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* dateTo;
 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* website;
 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* location;
 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString* jobDescription;
@end
```

In the data model I have one entity `User` where `jobExperience` attribute defined as `transformable`. That's why I implement NSCoding methods in it.
Here is  my mapping for `User`:

```
 _sharedUserProfileMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class]];
    [_sharedUserProfileMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[
                                                               @"name", @"surname",
                                                               @"hobbies", @"interests",
                                                       @"contact_address", @"contact_email"
                                                              ]];

    RKObjectMapping* mappingForJobExperience = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[JobExperience class]];
    [mappingForJobExperience addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[
                                                             @"location",
                                                             @"website", @"organization" ,
                                                             @"position"  ,
                                                             @"date_from", @"date_to"
                                                             ]];

    [mappingForJobExperience addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"description": @"jobDescription"}];

    [_sharedUserProfileMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"job_experience" mapping:mappingForJobExperience];
```

As you can see I add relationship mapping. When `User` was just an `NSObject` subclass all mapped perfectly!!! But when I made it `NSManagedObject` subclass I got an exception:

Mapping a to-many relationship for an `NSManagedObject`. About to apply value via    mutable[Set|Array]ValueForKey
    restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:726 Mapped `NSArray` relationship object from   keyPath 'job_experience' to 'jobExperience'. Value: (
    "",
    ""
)
  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSManagedObjects of entity 'User' do not support -mutableArrayValueForKey: for the property 'jobExperience''
*** First throw call stack:

And just for clarifying other attributes map perfectly. The problem only with this array of `JobExperience` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could be falling into an area that isn't implemented here. An outer object with an array of managed objects works (IIRC), but from your description and outer managed object and an array of objects doesn't work. It doesn't help that you aren't actually showing the different mappings that do and don't work though...

RestKit should be introspecting on the destination data type to decide what to do. Perhaps that doesn't work for this situation as it is provided with a relationship spec, it may assume that the destination is a Core Data relationship.

In any case, it's unusual to have a managed object with an array of custom objects. Usually you would use 2 managed objects and a relationship between the entities. This makes more sense and provides more expressive power and efficiency at runtime. This is what I'd recommend.

It could be that you need to set `mappingForJobExperience.forceCollectionMapping = YES;` to make it work (a guess).

Comment: 'forceCollectionMapping = YES' - this does't help.What do you mean by outer object? So you don't have any solution for this? But in a future  except jobExperience there will be added more objects like `UserSkill`, `UserEducation` and so on and so forth. I should create an NSManagedObject and a relationship with `User` for all of them?

Answer (score 0):

RestKit implicitly presumes that a to-many relationship modelled as an array or a set in a `NSManagedObject` maps to a CoreData entity. One solution is what the previous answer proposed: model your array attribute as a separate entity. If that's impractical for your design and you really want to keep the attribute as a Transformable, you may overwrite `mutableArrayValueForKey`. This could be a possible implemention appropriate for your initial example:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) mutableArrayValueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    if ( [key isEqualToString: @"jobExperience"] )
    {
        NSMutableArray * mutableJobExperience = [NSMutableArray array];
        if ( self.jobExperience != nil )
        {
            mutableJobExperience.array = self.jobExperience;
        }
        self.jobExperience = mutableJobExperience;
        return mutableJobExperience;
    } else {
        return [super mutableArrayValueForKey: key];
    }
}
```

The downside of this simple implementation is that we are turning `jobExperience` into a mutable array. That can probably be fixed at a later stage in your code, after results have been mapped completely.

Another solution would be to patch RestKit to behave differently in this situation. I would suggest to modify the method `- (BOOL)mapCoreDataToManyRelationshipValue:(id)valueForRelationship withMapping:(RKRelationshipMapping *)relationshipMapping` of `RKMappingOperation` to return `NO` if a mutable proxy cannot be obtained. That should do the trick.